# Continuity of function from extended complex plane to complex projective line

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I'm trying to show that the following map $f : C^+ \mapsto PC^1$ from the extended complex plane to the complex projective line is continuous and has an inverse that is also continuous :

$$f(z) \mapsto \begin{cases}
[(z,1)] &\text{if } z \in \mathbb{C} \\
[(1,0)] &\text{if } z = \infty
  \end{cases}$$

Now I figured out that the inverse function is given
$$f^{-1}([(z,w])) \mapsto \begin{cases}
z/w &\text{if } [(z,w)] \ne [(1,0)] \\
\infty &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$

I can see that my function $f(z)$ is certainly continuous when $z$ is just an ordinary complex number (since it's basically the identity map), but I'm not sure how to show that it is continuous when $z = \infty$. Similarly the continuity for the inverse function is trivial when the image is not infinity, but I'm not sure about the other part. I suppose I need to show that for any sequence $(z_n) \rightarrow \infty$, $f(z_n) \rightarrow (1,0)$ and similarly for any sequence $(z_n, w_n) \rightarrow (1,0)$, $f^{-1}([(z_n, w_n)]) \rightarrow \infty$ . However I'm not sure on how to proceed to show that this is the case.

Comment: Does $[z,1]=[1,1/z]$ help?

Comment: The topology at $\infty$ is the one inherited from $z\to 1/z, |z|<1$, so look at the continuity of $1/f^{-1}$ near $[(1,0)]$ (the standard notation is $[1:0]$)